# Links on BxSlider not working in Google Chrome but working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, bxslider

The error message on clicking is

jquery.js:4388 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchmove' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

I can open the link with right-click in a new tap. The more important left-click is not working.

On all other browsers the links are working fine

Please help me

Comment: Please help me to sort out the problem rather than downvoting?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. FYI I didn't downvote you...yet.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Author of the plugin is aware of this bug. 
You can track the progress here [bxSlider issues](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/issues)

Quick workaround while waiting for the patch is to set **touchEnabled** to false.

```
$('.your-slider').bxSlider({
        touchEnabled: false
    });
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is back again as of today.

Answer (score 7):

Altenatively in your jquery.bxslider.js file:
Replace this:

```js
if (slider.settings.touchEnabled && !slider.settings.ticker) { initTouch(); }
```

With this:

```js
if (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) { initTouch(); }
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I reverted to `bxslider Version 4.2.1.` , since I couldn't wait for the bugfix neither was I willing to disable the "touchEnabled" setting nor to touch the library code. With this version every thing works as it should (even in Chrome 77).

Comment: I just confirmed version 4.2.1 handles click properly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Altenatively in your jquery.bxslider.js file: Replace this:

```
if (slider.settings.touchEnabled && !slider.settings.ticker) { initTouch(); }
```

With this:

```
if (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) { initTouch(); }
```

Thank you Herbert